# nginx as frontend for apache

Tags: apache, nginx

I have nginx as frontend for apache. Apache listen port 8008.

Nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name SERVER_NAME;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:8008;
        }    
}
```

When I open url SERVER_NAME, browser actualy opens url SERVER_NAME:8008. And apache respons to the browser, not nginx.

Comment: You need to paste also your Apache config. BTW, why do you want to use nginx with apache, most of their features is overlapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the forwarding if you want your proxy to act as front-end.

Thy just this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name SERVER_NAME;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:8008;
        }    
}
```

Comment: @SergeyKolesov Cool. Now, just curious: why do you use both Apache and nginx ? Is that part of a migration process ?

Comment: No it's wordpress site. It doesn't work with nginx with first try and I do it with apache.